# php artisan make:auth does not create auth controllers after deleting

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

So I am working with Laravel authentication, first time it works perfectly but after deleting Auth folder, I run php artisan make:auth again but it does not create another Auth folder. The view and model part still runs well. Is there anyway to take it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command is not supposed to generate auth controllers for you. It generates appropriate auth views, routes and a `HomeController`. Quoting from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication):

> `php artisan make:auth`
>
> This command should be used on fresh applications and will install a layout view, registration and login views, as well as routes for all authentication end-points. A  HomeController will also be generated to handle post-login requests to your application's dashboard.

If the code is under git, you can simply restore your deleted files:

```
git checkout <commit> app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php
```

Or you can simply get your new copy from Laravel's repo:

```
wget -O app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/laravel/5.1/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php
```

Comment: It was there before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change permission to:

- `chmod 0755 Auth`
- `chmod g+w Auth`

After this two steps should work

Answer (score 0):

**auth** folder **NOT** generated by `php artisan make:auth` .

This **folder** and Its **internal controller  files** generated when you installed a **fresh** `laravel` .

Maybe you removed this folder .

Install a fresh `laravel` and copy **auth folder** in your project .